# Twilio Video for iOS crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio

I'm building an iOS app using Twilio-Video (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video).
My app running on iPhone SE received error messages and crashed in 10 seconds after local video track enabled.

```
2016-09-05 11:23:45.676 MyApp[4818:256404] INFO:TwilioConversations:[Core]:Media track changed trackId: bcd5bf96a31e1c928950b3195aa83598c993 enabled: 1
2016-09-05 11:23:45.862 MyApp[4818:255337] INFO:TwilioConversations:[Signaling]:RESIP::DUM: Got: SipResp: 200 tid=6abfba7dd0228d35 cseq=2 PUBLISH / 2 from(wire)
2016-09-05 11:23:46.809 MyApp[4818:253499] ERROR:TwilioConversations:[Platform]:Failed to get a drawable!
2016-09-05 11:23:47.814 MyApp[4818:253499] ERROR:TwilioConversations:[Platform]:Failed to get a drawable!
2016-09-05 11:23:48.818 MyApp[4818:253499] ERROR:TwilioConversations:[Platform]:Failed to get a drawable!
2016-09-05 11:23:49.823 MyApp[4818:253499] ERROR:TwilioConversations:[Platform]:Failed to get a drawable!
2016-09-05 11:23:50.824 MyApp[4818:253499] ERROR:TwilioConversations:[Platform]:Failed to get a drawable!
2016-09-05 11:23:51.827 MyApp[4818:253499] ERROR:TwilioConversations:[Platform]:Failed to get a drawable!
2016-09-05 11:23:52.828 MyApp[4818:253499] ERROR:TwilioConversations:[Platform]:Failed to get a drawable!
2016-09-05 11:23:53.830 MyApp[4818:253499] ERROR:TwilioConversations:[Platform]:Failed to get a drawable!
2016-09-05 11:23:54.125 MyApp[4818:256404] INFO:TwilioConversations:[Core]:PeerConnection: connection completed.
2016-09-05 11:23:54.833 MyApp[4818:253499] ERROR:TwilioConversations:[Platform]:Failed to get a drawable!
2016-09-05 11:23:55.836 MyApp[4818:253499] ERROR:TwilioConversations:[Platform]:Failed to get a drawable!
2016-09-05 11:23:56.838 MyApp[4818:253499] ERROR:TwilioConversations:[Platform]:Failed to get a drawable!
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Metal/Metal-56.7/ToolsLayers/Debug/MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder.mm:524: failed assertion `For depth attachment, the renderPipelineState pixelFormat must be MTLPixelFormatInvalid, as no texture is set.'
```

Stack trace.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x3de3b, 0x0000000181f1811c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0000000181f1811c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000181fe4ef8 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 112
    frame #2: 0x0000000181e89dc8 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 140
    frame #3: 0x0000000181e5ee54 libsystem_c.dylib`__assert_rtn + 284
    frame #4: 0x00000001844b533c Metal`MTLReportFailure + 480
    frame #5: 0x00000001973056dc MetalTools`-[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder validateFramebufferWithRenderPipelineState:] + 1292
    frame #6: 0x0000000197305ba0 MetalTools`-[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder setRenderPipelineState:] + 356
  * frame #7: 0x00000001002e42b0 MyApp`-[TWCMetalRenderer encode:](self=0x0000000159293680, _cmd=<unavailable>, renderEncoder=<unavailable>) + 124 at TWCMetalRenderer.mm:392 [opt]
    frame #8: 0x00000001002e4514 MyApp`-[TWCMetalRenderer render:frame:](self=0x0000000159293680, _cmd=<unavailable>, view=<unavailable>, frame=<unavailable>) + 220 at TWCMetalRenderer.mm:438 [opt]
    frame #9: 0x00000001003012d4 MyApp`-[TWCMetalView display](self=0x000000015955eb10, _cmd=<unavailable>) + 328 at TWCMetalView.mm:256 [opt]
    frame #10: 0x00000001002d4c2c MyApp`-[TWCMetalVideoRenderer renderingloop](self=<unavailable>, _cmd=<unavailable>) + 204 at TWCMetalVideoRenderer.m:210 [opt]
    frame #11: 0x00000001002d4a48 MyApp`__46-[TWCMetalVideoRenderer dispatchRenderingLoop]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=<unavailable>) + 36 at TWCMetalVideoRenderer.m:139 [opt]
    frame #12: 0x00000001002e4ef8 MyApp`-[TWCDisplayLinkTimer displayLinkDidFire:](self=<unavailable>, _cmd=<unavailable>, displayLink=<unavailable>) + 28 at TWCDisplayLinkTimer.mm:65 [opt]
    frame #13: 0x0000000100c74aa0 libMTLInterpose.dylib`-[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 184
    frame #14: 0x0000000184eb822c QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 40
    frame #15: 0x0000000184eb80e0 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 424
    frame #16: 0x00000001825f5e54 IOKit`IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372
    frame #17: 0x000000018231d030 CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 180
    frame #18: 0x00000001823357d4 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
    frame #19: 0x0000000182334f0c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
    frame #20: 0x0000000182332c64 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1800
    frame #21: 0x000000018225cc50 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    frame #22: 0x0000000183b44088 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 180
    frame #23: 0x000000018754a088 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 204
    frame #24: 0x00000001000d5e40 MyApp`main + 144 at AppDelegate.swift:27
    frame #25: 0x0000000181dfa8b8 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

What does  "Failed to get a drawable" mean ?

Details:

- TwilioConversationsClient 0.25.1(Twilio Common 0.3.1)
- My app sends invite repeatedly until participant rejects it, and creates TWCLocalMedia instance each time. (wrong?)
- App doesn't crash when iPhone SE accepts incoming invite.

Comment: Can you share the code that is causing this error? What have you implemented? What's the full description of what happens (you send an invite, accept invite, load media, crash?)

Answer (score 0):

- Open the *Edit Scheme*,
- Uncheck *Debug executable* in *Info* segment
- Run again!

Comment: This may help you solve the bug temporary,but if do that,you can never debug and log the Info with breakpoint angin, so if somebody has better method, add comment to me please!